# Asp net validation error message is never display

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation, visibility, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm using a RequiredFieldValidator to check a field as follow :

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="field" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="field" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="*" />
```

I use dynamic display because I don't want the validator to eat space in my page if the input is right. The validator is rendered like this when the input is fine :

```
<span id="messageError" style="color: Red; display: none; visibility: hidden;">Numeric format required</span>
```

My issue is when the validation fires an error, the message switch to "display: inline" but is still "visibility: hidden", so it is never displayed

```
<span id="messageError" style="color: Red; display: inline; visibility: hidden;">* Required</span>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `ErrorMessage="*"` property instead of `Text="*"`

It should be like...

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="field"
Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="*" />
```